# JQL - Search for value in multiple fields by typing it once

Tags: jira, jql

I want to write this JQL query in a way that I don't need to replace all occurences of "value" many times whenever I need to search for a new one.

```
comment ~ "value" OR description ~ "value" OR summary ~ "value" OR assignee = "value" ORDER BY created DESC
```

Is that possible ? Something like this:

```
"value" IN (comment, description, summary, assignee)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is not too wide approach but using simply

```
text ~ "value"
```

searches in all searchable text fields in issues.

Comment: This doesn't work for the non-searchable text fields such as "assignee", but I marked it as the correct answer since it seems to be the closest as we can possibly get to my original question